# What is the meaning of “von sich” in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of ,,von sich" in the following sentence?

> In der Mitte Deutschlands schrumpft ein Landkreis vor sich hin, der von sich behauptet, über Jahrhunderte „mit Weitsicht“ gewachsen zu sein.

Answer (score 3):

"der von sich behauptet" = "who claims to be", "who makes claims about himself"

If you move the nested clause, it may be clearer: In der Mitte Deutschlands schrumpft ein Landkreis, der von sich behauptet, über Jahrhunderte "mit Weitsicht" gewachsen zu sein, vor sich hin.

Answer (score 0):

They're telling about **themselves** how they have grown up.

While
"Sie behaupten von den Amerikanern, sehr nett zu sein."
would mean that they're talking about the Americans.

Comment: I'd recommend to @rednaZ to change the example to "They're talking about how they themselves grew up" even if I'm not sure if it is a good example in the first place. Neither is second example, I'm afraid, because you would expect a "dass" after "sie behaupten" if it doesn't relate to those who claim something; thus, "Sie behaupten von sich, sehr nett zu sein" would be the better choice, I think.